# Not sure this usage of volatile makes sense, seems to have the same issue

Tags: java, concurrency

Reading here:

[JLS 8.3.1.4 volatile Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.4)

Without `volatile` it says

> "then method two could occasionally print a value for `j` that is greater than the value of `i`, because the example includes no synchronization and"

```
class Test {
    static volatile int i = 0, j = 0;
    static void one() { i++; j++; }
    static void two() {
        System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    }
}
```

With volatile is says

> "It is possible, however, that any given invocation of method two might observe a value for `j` that is much greater than the value observed for `i`, because method one might be executed many times between the moment when method two fetches the value of `i` and the moment when method two fetches the value of `j`."

In behaves 'properly' with synchornization, but I'm confused as to what benefit `volatile` brings here?

I thought `volatile` gaurantees the order is preserved, so I would have thought it SOME cases the value of i might be greater than `j`, but not the other way around since that implies the order of incrementing was changed.

Is that a typo in the doc?  If not, please explain how `j` could be greater than `i` when using `volatile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that in the middle of method two method one could run several and that the value read for j would be higher than the value read for i.

```
read i
run method 1
run method 1
read j
```

Comment: ah ok, so j will always be less than or equal to i, but because of the delay in outputing it appears to be different.

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` variable tells the JIT compiler not to perform any optimizations that could affect the ordering of access to that variable. The writes to the volatile variable are always performed in the memory and never on the cache or cpu registers.

Also two more points:

- i++ is not a single operation but three: a) read variable i, b) increment, c) store. This "triple" operation is not atomic, meaning there is not a guarantee that would be completed without some other thread looking into its inconsistent state. If you want to do that look at [AtomicInteger#getAndIncrement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)
- your method one() is not synchronised therefore you can have one thread having completed i++ then the second thread prints and the first thread completes the j++ operation then.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, volatile guarantees that different threads will reference the same variable instead of copying it, i.e., if you update a volatile variable in a thread, all others will have this variable update because they all reference the same. A good example of this can be found at [Why Volatile Matters](http://java.dzone.com/articles/threading-stories-why-volatile).

The thing about method two is that it isn't Atomic. It won't run in only one CPU cycle. You can divide it in different operations like @Sign stated. Even i++ isn't atomic,  as it needs to read variable i, incremente it and store it again at i reference in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You got the behavior of volatile right; you just didn't read what you quote carefully:

> because method one might be executed many times between the moment
>   when method two fetches the value of i and the moment when method two
>   fetches the value of j

The order is preserved in `one()`, it's that in `two()`, `i` is fetched and printed, but in the time it takes to print `i` both `i` and `j` might be incremented many times by calls to `one()` from other threads and so the printed value for `j` will be higher than the printed value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

volatile makes reading OR writing thread safe/memory consistent. It doesn't make reading AND writing atomic however. Using `volatile` is only fine if only one thread will ever update it.

I suggest you use AtomicInteger instead.

Answer (score 0):

In "source code order", increments to `i` *happen-before* increments to `j`. So, a thread invoking method `one()` will always observe that `i >= j`. But, when other threads observe those variables, they can see things differently.

There are certain events that establish what the JLS calls "synchronization order." It makes sense to talk about these events (and *only* these events) as "happening before" others. Writing to a volatile variable is one of these. Without using `volatile`, it doesn't make any sense to say that `i` is incremented *before* `j`; those writes could be re-ordered, and that re-ordering can be observed by other threads.

A better example for what can happen without `volatile` would be this:

```
static void oneAndAHalf() { System.out.println("j=" + j + " i=" + i);
```

Even though `j` *appears* to be incremented *after* `i`, and `j` is fetched *before* `i`, you could still observe `j > i` because the removal of `volatile` would permit the operations in `one()` to be reordered. Add `volatile`, and `oneAndAHalf()` will always show `i >= j`, as you expect.

If you take away `volatile`, then method `two()` could print a value for `j` that is greater than `i` for either of two reasons: because operations have been reordered, *or* because `i` and `j` are not treated atomically. The current `two()` method doesn't unambiguously illustrate the utility of `volatile`. Add `volatile`, and you'll get the same output, but the only reason is that the operations are not atomic.

To see a consistent view, where `i == j`, both methods could be `synchronized`. This would make the increment to both variables appear to be atomic.

Comment: `volatile` does not allow operations to be reordered.  The problem comes from somewhere else (see my answer or the one by Sign).

Comment: @toto2 Right, I understand that, but maybe I didn't explain it clearly. My point was to show what the JLS authors were *trying* to illustrate, but did poorly. Their example doesn't make it clear that `volatile` prevents re-ordering. I rewrote my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: OK. [Apparently, I need at least 15 characters to post a comment.]